# How to delete a kubernetes deployment using kubernetes python client?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-python-client

I cannot find the python function to delete a kubernetes deployment. I can delete the pods but that would only cause the deployment to restart the pods again. Basically I want the equivalent of `kubectl delete deployment deployment1 --namespace nms`.

Comment: HI Sanjeeb, I am looking for the function to delete pods, you mentioned you got that right could you help me giving me the function name please etc. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn't exists a delete_from_yaml.py lib. After following several GitHub history the last update is 12d ago, apparently because it lacks contributors. ( https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/pull/1392 )

[image]

Solutions:

- Maybe you can use the code proposed in the above PR
- Create your own PR
- use `kubectl delete` command for this...

Bguess